# How to use hook in server side render on next js?

Tags: typescript, next.js

But can't use hook in  server-side render page

**Example:**

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx:any) => {
   
    const { data } = useLocalStorage()

    return {
        props: { data : data}
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do that, React hooks can only be used in React components. Also, you wouldn't be able to access `localStorage` on the server anyway. Move that logic to the client code.

Comment: If you need some user's data in the server-side though, you could always store the data you need in a cookie, which you will be able to access in the `NextRequest` available in the context: `ctx.req.cookies`

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can use hooks on server-side.

In general Hooks are just normal functions.
The issue is, as soon as you try to access something that exists only in the browser e.g. `window`, `localStorage`, etc. the server will resign knowing it's a client-only job.

```js
// src/hooks/useOnServer.ts
import { useIsSSR } from "@react-aria/ssr";

/**
 * useIsSSR is another hook that returns true if on server-side.
 * in the browser it logs 'Client', on the server 'Server'
 * (btw the package also offers a SSRProvider to wrap your `<App />` with.
 */
export default function useOnServer() {
  const isServer = useIsSSR();

  console.log(isServer ? "Server" : "Client");
}
```

And here how to use it:

```js
// src/pages/home.tsx
import useOnServer from "src/hooks/useOnServer";

export default function Home() {
  // boom!
  useOnServer();

  return <p>hurray! it worked!</p>
}
```

it's the full power of isomorphic coding.
You could e.g.

- write a validator to **only once implement form validation**, a classic redundant server & client challenge, which is very error-prone IMO because a backender and a frontender need to sync every time the form needs adaption.
  Then you need: 2 scripts, 2 dev's, 2 test files, manual syncing...

it's like a ticking time bomb  MeteorJS was probably first that came up with a isomorphic framework (or it was the first I was using years ago)

obviously it requires a bit of  and has its learning curve, but the benefits are more than compensation. Enjoy coding your first isomorphic hook and let us know if you decide to open-source it!

Comment: furthermore, if you want to use localStorage isomorphic, you would have to implement a server-side `localStorage` implementation (maybe already exists somewhere, well maybe they won't call it 'local'Storage but an existing example: MeteorJS implemented https://github.com/rezen/mini-mongo = MongoDB running on client (and syncing with server-side MongoDB) ...nothing not possible in-between zero and one 